# How to achieve nested INSERT statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, insert, common-table-expression

I have two tables, `group` and `groupmembers`. On insertion of a row in the `group` table, I also want to insert two values, `groupid` (id from group table) and `userid` (id of the user that created the group) into the `groupmembers` table. These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
  creator CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
  role CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('admin'),
  createdon TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  FOREIGN KEY (creator) references users (email) on delete CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE groupmembers (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  groupid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  createdon TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  FOREIGN KEY (groupid) references groups (id) on delete CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) references users (id) on delete CASCADE
);

 CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    firstname CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    lastname CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    email CHARACTER VARYING(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    registeredon TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
  );
```

The insert statement into the group table is:

```
INSERT INTO groups (name, creator) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *;
```

How do I add another insert statement that inserts values into `groupid` and `userid` columns of `groupmembers` table?

I have seen this, but it doesn't seem to answer my question:
[PostgreSQL nested INSERTs / WITHs for foreign key insertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386772/postgresql-nested-inserts-withs-for-foreign-key-insertions)

Comment: @KenWhite; thanks for the good spot. my caps lock was actually on. Thanks

Comment: Where will the `userid` to insert into the new `groupmembers` record come from?

Comment: @404 it will come from the users table

Comment: How? You showed an insertion into `groups`, and presumably `id` from the inserted record will be `groupid` in `groupmembers`, but then how do you know which user id to use?

Comment: @404: Did you see `FOREIGN KEY (creator) references users (email) on delete CASCADE`? That's how.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to wrap both inserts in a single query with a [**data-modifying CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), like:

```
WITH grp_ins AS (
   INSERT INTO groups (name, creator)
   VALUES ($1, $2)
   RETURNING id, creator
   )
INSERT INTO groupmembers (groupid, userid)
SELECT g.id, u.id 
FROM   grp_ins    g
JOIN   users u ON u.email = g.creator;
```

Since `groups.creator` is defined `NOT NULL` with an FK constraint enforcing referential integrity, an `[INNER] JOIN` is good. Else I'd consider a `LEFT JOIN`.

Much like [the answer you referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387005/939860) to. Or these ones:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)
- [Insert inserted id to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588544/insert-inserted-id-to-another-table/27589070#27589070)

If, for some reason, you cannot enforce above command (like nested in a function that has to be used for inserts to `groups`), **the next best thing** is a  [**trigger**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html) `AFTER INSERT` to execute the second `INSERT`. A bit more complex and costly. But does the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_ins_row_in_groupmembers()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO groupmembers (groupid, userid)
   SELECT NEW.id, (SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.email = NEW.creator);

   RETURN NEW;  -- doesn't matter much what you return here
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And a trigger `AFTER INSERT` on `groups`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER groups_ins_aft
AFTER INSERT ON groups
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_ins_row_in_groupmembers();
```

Related:

- [On INSERT to a table INSERT data in connected tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119005/on-insert-to-a-table-insert-data-in-connected-tables/10402234#10402234)